# How can I set a datatrigger for a list view depending on a cell value?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

Hi I used to use a datagrid but it was soooo slow when working with tabs, so I switched to ListView but I don't know how to style it, (it's a lot more complicated than DataGrid in my opinion).

So I was wondering how to do this for ListView:

```
<Style x:Key="gridCell" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
   Value="{StaticResource lightBlueBrush}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="Otpisano">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And then in the View

```
CellStyle="{StaticResource gridCell}"
```

Comment: but why your datagrid was so slow? have you tried using Background worker.

Comment: I do not know why, I just know it took it 18 seconds to show 2300 rows. With ListView it takes 6

Comment: Was Virtualization activated ?

Comment: No... Virtualization was not activated

Comment: I didn't know about any of these things I just read that DataGrid sucks with Tabs and that one should use ListView...

Comment: If you guys can tell me how to enable these things and if they will make my application faster I can go back to datagrid

Comment: Actually upon reading about it Virtualization is activated by default in datagrid if you use ItemsSource Binding and I did... So maybe it was on

Comment: from where you read that datagrid is slow with tabs?

Comment: Did you set your Datagrid's ItemsSource inside the TabControl's Content? If so, do not use the Tabcontrol Content, make it collapsed. Make a Grid with two rows and row 1 will be your tabcontrol and row 2 with be your DataGrid and do use virtualization..

Comment: On the TabSelectionChanged event you can just change the Itemsource.

Comment: While I thank you for your input this is probably not the right place. I figured out how to set the style for this type of View so I will mark this as answered. If I decide to go back to DataGrid I will make a new question. Thing is it works perfect in a new window... Anyway thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do the Styling:

[Answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c2558545-f9fd-43b4-a7a5-a9fdc10d0be1)